# Switching the text on a JButton

Tags: java, swing, if-statement, jbutton

This one may be easy for you. But I'm stuck and can't figure out an algorithm for doing that. I want to show a JTextField and change the text on the JButton to "Hide" if it's "Search". If 
the text on the JButton is "Search" a JTextBox should appear and vice versa, if the text is "Hide" make the JTextField invisivle and change the text on JButton to "Search"
This is how I have done it:

```
private void switchBtnText(){
 searchTxtField.setVisible(true);
 btnSearch.setText("Hide");

 if(btnSearch.getText().equals("Hide")){
     btnSearch.setText("Search");
     searchTxtField.setVisible(false);
 }
}
```

If I comment the if section it works to show the JTextField. My problem is to go back to the default settings which is a JButton with "Search" as a text and with an invisible JTextField.
The method is then called in an ActionEvent. I've done this before, in C#, so I know I'm close. 
Thank you in advance. The fastest and best answer will get upvoted and accepted.

Answer (score 4):

This should work although I've not tested it.

```
//btn action

private void toggleVisible(){
    String btnVal = btnSearch.getText();
    if(btnVal.equals("Search")){
        searchTxtField.setVisible(true); // or however you are showing search field
        btnSearch.setText("Hide");
    }else{
         searchTxtField.setVisible(false);
         btnSearch.setText("Search");
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried exactly as you said but it doesn't work. Thanks for your answer. EDI: Oh in the actionEvent I had used getActionCommand to see if the button "Search" was clicked. I changed that to getSource() instead and it worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your execution sequence....

- setText to "Hide"
- if text equals "Hide", change text to "Show"

Try changing the logic so you check the text first, then make decisions about what should be done...

- If text equals "Hide", change text to "Show"
- Else, change text to "Hide"